# Windows server 2016 Standard detects as windows 2012

Tags: python, windows

I have a Python script that one of his first operations is to detect the OS version of the Windows server it's running on, but I encountered a problem that one of my Windows Server 2016 Standard is detects as Windows 2012.

Output from tests I made on the Windows Server 2016:

```
import platform
import sys

>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-2012Server-6.2.9200'    
>>> sys.getwindowsversion()
sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=2, build=9200, platform=2, service_pack='')
```

Build 9200 is Windows 2012.

Also this is the Registry from "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"

[image]

Do you know why this is happening and which other way can I check the OS version?
I just need to figure it out if the machine is Windows Server 2016 or not.

Thanks

Comment: If the manifest of python.exe doesn't specify a [supported OS version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481241), the reported version will be no higher than Windows 8 (6.2), build 9200. But `platform()` should work. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: The Python I'm using is 2.7.4. I meant that I need to detect the OS version for the script logic, not for the Python itself. I will clarify it above.

Comment: `sys.getwindowsversion` isn't going to return the true version, not even in the most recent release of Python 2. The problem with `platform()` is probably that you're using 2.7.4 from 2013. Can you update to 2.7.13?

Comment: I can use 2.7.8. will it solve the issue? and another problem is why the Registry value is 6.3 when it should be 10.0?

Comment: You could try 2.8, but I think it was fixed a couple years ago in the 2.7.10 release. As to "CurrentVersion" in the registry, I suppose that was left at 6.3 for backward compatibility. Windows 10 uses "CurrentMajorVersionNumber" and "CurrentMinorVersionNumber", which are visible in your screenshot.

Comment: The "CurrentMajorVersionNumber" and ""CurrentMinorVersionNumber" is good for me. Thank! If you want, please answer in another comment so I will mark it as an answer